# What is the best table Structure for an ORM

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, orm

I have 4 tables related like so

```
+-----------+    +------------+    +---------+    +----------+
|  Project  |    | Slide      |    | Shape   |    |  Points  |
+-----------+    +------------+    +---------+    +----------+
|    id     |    |  id        |    | id      |    | id       |
+-----------+    | project_id |    |slide_id |    | shape_id |
                 +------------+    +---------+    | x        |
                                                  | y        |
                                                  +----------+
```

From the ORM docs I have been reading for the Active record object built into CodeIgniter is it best to keep the tables structured like so or change them to one of the following ways.

First would be to use a total relational table like this

```
+-----------+    +------------+    +---------+    +----------+  +-------------------------------+
|  Projects |    | Slides     |    | Shapes  |    |  Points  |  | Projects_Slides_Shapes_Points |
+-----------+    +------------+    +---------+    +----------+  +-------------------------------+
|    id     |    |  id        |    | id      |    | id       |  | id                            |
+-----------+    +------------+    +---------+    | x        |  | Project_id                    |
                                                  | y        |  | Slide_id                      |
                                                  +----------+  | Shape_id                      |
                                                                | Point_id                      )
                                                                +-------------------------------+
```

That way everything is related by one table or should I relate things with seperate tables so instead of the above it the relation tables would look like so.

```
+-----------------+   +---------------+  +---------------+
| Projects_Slides |   | Slides_Shapes |  | Shapes_Points |
+-----------------+   +---------------+  +---------------+
| id              |   | id            |  | id            |
| Project_id      |   | Slide_id      |  | Shape_id      |
| Slide_id        |   | Shape_id      |  | Point_id      |
+-----------------+   +---------------+  +---------------+
```

The first way will have a smaller number of entries but less queries to build the ORM object on the other hand the other has less entries and more queries. I really don't know which is best or which an ORM prefers. Or if an ORM can handle one or the other.

Or for an ORM can I keep them like they are and I am misunderstanding the docs.

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: What does the 'cont_id' refer to in the 'Shape' table?

Comment: Yeah edited to make sense, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first determine what kind of relationships you're going to have between the four different object you have defined.

For example, there is no need to create a "Projects_Slides" table unless you have a many-to-many relationship between "Project" and "Slides". As it is, I assume that you would like each Project to have many slides, and each slide to be associated with only one Project? In this case, you have a one-to-many relationship and the first schema would be best.

If you were to define that a Slide could belong to more than one Project, then that would be a many-to-many relationship and the "Projects_Slides" table would make sense.

Comment: The table all have a one to many relationship, so for project -> slide -> shape -> points, its project(one) -> slide(many), slide(one) -> shape(many), shape(one) -> points(many)

Comment: In this case I would use the first schema.

Comment: So with that structure I cannot figure out how to use an ORM, if you don't mind giving an example. The ORM I am using is the one built into codeigniter but I am not apposed to used to any that are recommend.

Comment: I haven't used Codeigniter before, but from the documentation at: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/ActiveRecord_Class/. To retrieve all the slides for a Project you would go $project = $this->Project->find_by_id(1);  $projectSlides = $project->fetch_related_slides();

Answer (score 0):

Did you intend for the Shapes table to be self referential (it has id and shape_id columns)?

Generally, ORM's are happiest when you properly normalize your database.  I'd say your first example is the most properly normalized, if you're trying to do what I think you are.

Comment: I edited it sorry I am a little brain dead now I guess.  What would be a normalized db for a project that contains a set of slides that contain a set of shapes that contain a set of points?

Comment: The first set of tables at the top is the most properly normalized for your case of nested one to many relationships.  I would go with that structure.  The others are kind of kludgy and in some cases may be necessary for performance optimization, but usually, a by the book normalized database works better with most ORM frameworks.